# php: split string until first occurance of a number

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-split

i have string like

```
cream 100G
sup 5mg Children
```

i want to split it before the first occurrence of a digit. so the result should be

```
array(
    array('cream','100G'),
    array('sup','5mg Children')
);
```

can so one tell me how to create pattern for this ?

i tried

```
list($before, $after) = array_filter(array_map('trim',
            preg_split('/\b(\d+)\b/', $t->formula)), 'strlen');
```

but something went wrong.

Comment: Is `preg_split('/(?=\d)/', $input, 2)` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions for that:

```
$str = 'cream 100g';

$p = strcspn($str, '0123456789');
$before = substr($str, 0, $p);
$after = substr($str, $p);

echo "before: $before, after: $after";
```

See also: [`strcspn()`](http://php.net/strcspn)

> Returns the length of the initial segment of `$str` which does not contain any of the characters in `'0123456789'`, aka digits.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
<?php 

$first_string = "abc2 2mg";
print_r( preg_split('/(?=\d)/', $first_string, 2));

?>
```

Will output:

```
Array ( [0] => abc [1] => 2 2mg )
```

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression solution would be to call `preg_split` as

```
preg_split('/(?=\d)/', $t->formula, 2)
```

The main point here is that you do not consume the digit used as the split delimiter by using positive lookahead instead of capturing it (so that it remains in `$after`) and that we ensure the split produces no more than two pieces by using the third argument.